# Faster alternative to count value from 2 queries and select with WITH

Tags: postgresql-10

I have a query which I have to make it run faster.
This is my best shot.
Any recommendations that I can improve this?

```
WITH cm 
     AS (SELECT Count(*) AS count_messages 
         FROM   messages AS m 
         WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM   order_items AS o 
                               inner join orders ox 
                                       ON ox.order_id = o.order_id 
                        WHERE  m.product_id = o.product_id 
                               AND m.message_type = 0 
                               AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 ) 
                               AND current_date >= ox.order_creation_date)), 
     co 
     AS (SELECT Count(*) AS count_order_items 
         FROM   order_items AS o 
         WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM   messages AS m 
                               inner join orders oy 
                                       ON oy.order_id = o.order_id 
                        WHERE  m.product_id = o.product_id 
                               AND m.message_type = 0 
                               AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 ) 
                               AND current_date >= oy.order_creation_date)) 
SELECT cm.count_messages :: DECIMAL / co.count_order_items :: DECIMAL * 100 AS 
       result 
FROM   cm, 
       co
```

Comment: What's the execution plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to do query rewriting without knowing any keys etc, but if I'm not mistaken cm can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT Count(distinct m.message_id) AS count_messages
FROM   messages AS m
JOIN   order_items AS o
    ON m.product_id = o.product_id
JOIN   orders ox
    ON ox.order_id = o.order_id                               
WHERE m.message_type = 0
  AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 )                               
  AND current_date >= ox.order_creation_date
```

using the same technique and the fact that `A |x| B <=> B |x| A` give us:

```
SELECT Count(distinct o.order_item_id) AS count_order_items
FROM   messages AS m
JOIN   order_items AS o
    ON m.product_id = o.product_id
JOIN   orders ox
    ON ox.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE m.message_type = 0
  AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 )
  AND current_date >= ox.order_creation_date
```

for co. This can be combined to:

```
SELECT 100*Count(distinct m.message_id) :: Decimal 
         / Count(distinct o.order_item_id) :: Decimal 
FROM   messages AS m
JOIN   order_items AS o
    ON m.product_id = o.product_id
JOIN   orders ox
    ON ox.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE m.message_type = 0
  AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 )
  AND current_date >= ox.order_creation_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this might help?

```
 CREATE VIEW v1 AS 
    SELECT Count(*) AS count_messages 
             FROM   messages AS m 
             WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                            FROM   order_items AS o 
                                   inner join orders ox 
                                           ON ox.order_id = o.order_id 
                            WHERE  m.product_id = o.product_id 
                                   AND m.message_type = 0 
                                   AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 ) 
                                   AND current_date >= ox.order_creation_date);

CREATE VIEW v2 AS 
SELECT Count(*) AS count_order_items 
         FROM   order_items AS o 
         WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM   messages AS m 
                               inner join orders oy 
                                       ON oy.order_id = o.order_id 
                        WHERE  m.product_id = o.product_id 
                               AND m.message_type = 0 
                               AND m.seller_id IN( 3, 2, 6, 1, 9 ) 
                               AND current_date >= oy.order_creation_date);
```

-- for your required result:

```
SELECT (SELECT v1.count_messages)/(SELECT v2.count_order_items)::FLOAT
```

Can't test because I don't know your table structures, nor I have your data. However, here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a99a9732c413c7c18ea1df552c82f169) with a sample. But @Lennart's solution is much more elegant!